# Kolmogorov's three-series theorem - "only if"

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

During my probability theory course we try to prove the “only if” of the [Kolmogorov's three-series theorem](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj6-938ntnzAhWjQuUKHXLmDnIQFnoECBAQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FKolmogorov%2527s_three-series_theorem&usg=AOvVaw0DQ_Lop5_adBpbNmBBij5Y). One of the stepS is as follow: we have a sequence of independant random variable $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ that we know $S_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ is converging almost surely. Then we consider on some (new) probability space, a sequence $(Y’_1, Y’’_1, Y’_2, Y’’_2,\dots)$ of independent random variables such that $\forall n, Y’_n$ and $Y’’_n$ both have the law of $Y_n$. It is then stated that $S’_n$ and $S’’_n$ are converging almost surely. Where I see why $S’_n \sim S’’_n \sim S_n$ (Thanks to the indépendance and the law assumption), I don’t see why the convergence conclusion hold.
Could you please explain that ?

Many thanks by advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use that $(S_1,S_2,\ldots)$ and $(S'_1,S'_2,\ldots)$ have the same distribution in $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ (using the definition of the cylinder $\sigma$-field) to say that $1=\mathbb P(S_n\text{ converges})=\mathbb P(S'_n\text{ converges})$ or reprove this directly from the finite-dimensional marginal distributions as follows.

Because $(S'_n:N\le n\le N')\sim(S_n:N\le n\le N')$, we have
$$\mathbb P\!\left(\bigcap_{N\le n,m\le N'}\Bigl\{|S_n'-S'_m|\le\frac1k\Bigr\}\right)=\mathbb P\!\left(\bigcap_{N\le n,m\le N'}\Bigl\{|S_n-S_m|\le\frac1k\Bigr\}\right)\!,$$
for all $k\ge1$ and $N'\ge N\ge1$. Taking the non-increasing limit $N'\to\infty$ gives
$$\mathbb P\!\left(\bigcap_{n,m\ge N}\Bigl\{|S_n'-S'_m|\le\frac1k\Bigr\}\right)=\mathbb P\!\left(\bigcap_{n,m\ge N}\Bigl\{|S_n-S_m|\le\frac1k\Bigr\}\right)\!.$$
Now the underlying events are non-decreasing with $N$, so
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P\!\left(\bigcup_{N\ge1}\bigcap_{n,m\ge N}\Bigl\{|S_n'-S'_m|\le\frac1k\Bigr\}\right)&=\underset{N\uparrow\infty}{\mathrm{lim}{\uparrow}}\:\mathbb P\!\left(\bigcap_{n,m\ge N}\Bigl\{|S'_n-S'_m|\le\frac1k\Bigr\}\right)\\[.4em]&=\underset{N\uparrow\infty}{\mathrm{lim}{\uparrow}}\:\mathbb P\!\left(\bigcap_{n,m\ge N}\Bigl\{|S_n-S_m|\le\frac1k\Bigr\}\right)\\[.4em]&=\mathbb P\!\left(\bigcup_{N\ge1}\bigcap_{n,m\ge N}\Bigl\{|S_n-S_m|\le\frac1k\Bigr\}\right)\!,\end{align*}
for all $k\ge1$. Finally, the underlying events are non-increasing with $k\ge1$, so
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P\!\left(\bigcap_{k\ge1}\bigcup_{N\ge1}\bigcap_{n,m\ge N}\Bigl\{|S_n'-S'_m|\le\frac1k\Bigr\}\right)&=\underset{k\uparrow\infty}{\mathrm{lim}{\downarrow}}\:\mathbb P\!\left(\bigcup_{N\ge1}\bigcap_{n,m\ge N}\Bigl\{|S_n'-S'_m|\le\frac1k\Bigr\}\right)\\[.4em]
&=\underset{k\uparrow\infty}{\mathrm{lim}{\downarrow}}\:\mathbb P\!\left(\bigcup_{N\ge1}\bigcap_{n,m\ge N}\Bigl\{|S_n-S_m|\le\frac1k\Bigr\}\right)\\[.4em]
&=\mathbb P\!\left(\bigcap_{k\ge1}\bigcup_{N\ge1}\bigcap_{n,m\ge N}\Bigl\{|S_n-S_m|\le\frac1k\Bigr\}\right)\!.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot for this precise answer. Have a great day :)